# how to check media query on desktop

Tags: css, media-queries

Is there a way using css3 media queries in which you can change design in landscape and portrait.

So I want to check that effect. But how I can use in desktop. Is there any tool where I can use this effect like in jsfiddle?

Comment: Tried resizing the browser window?

Comment: can you please give example on fiddle only add label ,change background when orientation change

Answer (score 0):

Media queries respond to the size of the screen/viewport. Just resize your browser window.

Comment: can you please give example on fiddle only add label ,change background on fiddle

Comment: If you use chrome or firefox, they both have developer tools in them that allow you to do this. In chrome: Just press f12 and go to settings (little gear in bottom right corner). Then go to overrides and check enable. Then you can set device metrics right there.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is an example of css media queries, just resize the page
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewnicols/EfySx/2/) or [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/MfKzU/1/)

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
    .responsive-test {
        width: 1px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/magnus16/pen/HhmFg)! Try resizing your browser width to less than 600px

Answer (score 0):

Try this Chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/window-resizer/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh

I use it and it's very good.